# How to create a XSD which differs in validation on attribute value?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd

I have been searching for a while now, and came to the conclusion it may not be possible to change the validation per value of an attribute.

For example I have two "action" nodes, both with a "type" attribute and two elements ("name" and "description")

Only when the value of the "type" attribute is "1" it has an "a" element with "abc" child elements and when the "type" attibute is "2" it has a "bla" element with "yet" child elements.

Example of type 1

```
<action type="1">
  <name>yup</name>
  <description>yyy</description>
  <a>
    <abc>false</abc>
  </a>
</action>
```

Example of type 2

```
<action type="2">
  <name>yup2</name>
  <description>RRR</description>
  <bla>
    <yet />
  </bla>
</action>
```

I want to create one XSD* who whould check both types, is this possible? 
And if so, how?

- It has to be one XSD because I want to put the XSD on a XML column of a table of a MSSQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it is not possible with XSD 1.0 which is the only XSD version supported by MSSQL. The best you can get is to create a choice between `a` and `bla`, maybe place some constraints on attribute `type` values, etc. Below is an illustration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="action">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:choice>     
            <xs:element name="a">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="abc" type="xs:boolean" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="bla">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="yet" type="xs:anyType" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If you control the XML structure, and still want to use some attribute to control the content model, then xsi:type is the only way to do it in XSD 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool XML Stylus Studio to create any type of complex XSDs.

Check the details: http://www.stylusstudio.com/

Comment: That's quite generic answer.
I also tried to generate an XSD with XMLSpy, but it still didn't verify on value.